# Поиск вершины распада графа

Tags: алгоритм

Дано количество вершин(N). Далее идет описание N-1 ребра в графе, то есть начало и конец ребра. Путь между любыми двумя вершинами существует только один. Сам граф неориентированный.

Цель : найти такую вершину в графе, убрав которую, граф бы распался на минимум два новых графа меньшего размера, число вершин у которых одинаково. Если такой вершины не окажется -- вывести -1.

Я делал примерно следующим образом : для каждой вершины смотрел на смежные вершины и шел из них DFS при этом считая сколько вершин обойду. Потом, если количество вершин, которые DFS насчитал для каждой смежной вершины исходной вершины одинаково, то исходная вершина нам подходит.
Данное решение дает правильный ответ, но не проходит по времени. Я предполагаю, что есть более правильный подход к решению.

Answer (score 2):

По сути вам нужна вершина, у которой размеры всех поддеревье одинаковы. Например для цепочки это середина. Это можно сделать за линейно от числа вершин. Т.к.язык не указан, пишу в псевдокоде. Бонусом кстати можно найти *все* такие вершины.

```
void dfs(int current){
     size[current] = 1; // сама вершина
     sizePrev = -1;
     good = true;
     for (int parent : list(current) )
         tmp = dfs(parent);
         size[current] += tmp;
         if (sizePrev == -1)
            sizePrev = tmp;
         else if (sizePrev != tmp)
            good = false;

     if (sizePrev != N - size[current])
          good = false;
     if (good) 
          ANS.add(current);
     return size[current];
}
```

Идея в том, что мы запускаем поиск в глубину (от корня), и результат функции - число вершин в поддереве. При слиянии мы проверяем что все поддеревья равны и равны остатку сверху. Если это так, тогда вершина нам подходит.

Будьте внимательны, что бы не запустить функцию рекурсивно не только для потомков но и в сторону корня.

Comment: Вроде в условии ничего нет про размеры? Просто меньше, но они не могут оказаться такими же как весь граф. Получается, нужна любая.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну там написано распался на минимум 2 графа с равным числом вершин в каждом.

Comment: @pavel, то есть вы от каждой вершины запускаете функцию пока какая то не подойдет?

Comment: @marka_17 1 раз из корня дерева.

Comment: @pavel, так не факт что дерево бинарное. Какую вершину выбрать корнем?

Comment: @marka_17 а какая связь между бинарностью и корнем?) вообще любую можно выбрать корнем, главное чтобы определение потомка/предка было согласованно с корнем. Так-то хоть из 1 всегда вызывать можно.

Comment: @pavel, а можете написать код на с++, если Вам не сложно?

Comment: @marka_17 в целом ничего в коде и не поменялось. Остальное уже зависит от вас. Будут вопросы - выкладывайте код, подскажу.